# Slow Internet connection (WiFi) while using elementary OS Loki (Ralink RT3060)

Tags: release-loki, wifi, networking, internet

My **Internet connection** is painfully **slow** and irregular on **elementary OS Loki.**

I'm **connected** to the Internet **via WiFi through a PCI antenna**.

What I experience is that I get **disconnected from time to time**, also the **indicator shows a weak signal**, but I just restart the connection and it shows a strong one again.

Trying to download from the AppCenter or using *apt-get install* is horrible. Right now I'm downloading the openjdk-9-jre, is a 183 MB download that is taking from hours to days according to the Terminal. This same download on my Windows partition would take from 15 to 25 minutes top.

I tried to use Popcorn Time and the Internet connection kept slowing until reaching 0 kbps, then I would restart the connection, it would comeback up and then down again. Using Transmission for torrents gets me the same result.

Strangely, **I can browse the web and watch stuff like YouTube normally**.

**None of this** issues happen **on** my **Windows 10** partition, and they **didn't appear while using elementary OS Luna or Freya**.

If you need any Terminal input, just let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the output of "sudo lshw -C network"?

Comment: @bitseater 

`*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3060 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:04:05.0
       logical name: wlp4s5
       version: 00
       serial: 00:27:11:01:ec:35
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MH`

Comment: @bitseater `capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-57-generic firmware=0.34 ip=192.168.1.104 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=4 mingnt=2 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:20 memory:febf0000-febfffff`

Comment: @bitseater `*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 06
       serial: c8:60:00:5a:dd:85
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz`

Comment: @bitseater `capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:33 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdff8000-fdffbfff`

Comment: And now "sudo lsmod | grep wl"?

Comment: @bitseater 

wl                   6365184  0
cfg80211              565248  3 wl,mac80211,rt2x00lib

Comment: What is the result for `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Comment: I'd love to have some insight into this problem as well. I'm also on a Broadcom wireless adapter (BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter) and have spotty wireless. The big issue for me though, is that my modem broadcasts a regular and 5GHz signal, and I can't even see the 5GHz at all. I've tried all the suggestions I could find, including purging the existing drivers and getting it again, but no luck :(

Comment: Wow... okay.  Seeing this thread gave me the energy to go at it again, and I found a solution (for me, anyway). I went into my modem, and just on a whim, tried turning my wifi to be on a fixed broadcast channel instead of Auto.  After rebooting the modem, I can see the 5GHz signal for the first time!

Answer (score 1):

There are some known issues between Broadcom and Ralink drivers. You can try to remove and purge the first with:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and reboot your system.

If you hate reboot :P , you can try:

```
sudo modprobe -r rt2800pci
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe rt2800pci
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the end there seems to be an issue on how Loki (I'm guessing is a kernel problem) interacts with the driver of my old PCI Wi-Fi antena. I tried using an old USB antena and the Internet was working flawlessly.